# How can I delete rows if some condition in postgres

Tags: database, postgresql

I have some values in the database.

In a row, I have a `timestamp` column.

So I have `hash` identification for the group.

I can get the oldest time from group by (QUERY A):

```
SELECT last_hit as time
FROM cache 
WHERE hash = 'bba04f6985f560446c122d235ed2e51bf7c10864' 
ORDER BY time DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

How can I remove all items (`WHERE hash = 'bba04f6985f560446c122d235ed2e51bf7c10864`) if the result of query is older then 30 minut?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the current timestamp an subtract the timestamp in the column from it. Then compare to a 30 minute interval.

```
DELETE FROM cache
       WHERE hash = 'bba04f6985f560446c122d235ed2e51bf7c10864'
             AND statement_timestamp() - last_hit > '00:30:00'::interval;
```

`statement_timestamp()` gets the current timestamp when the statement begins. Other options are `now()` to get the timestamp of the beginning of the transaction and `clock_timestamp()` which changes during the execution of the statement. Change it to your needs. More information can be found in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html).